# How show/draw a image in the desktop pyqt?

Tags: python, linux, qt, svg, pyqt

Thats the question, how show images in the desktop, no images in a windows, something like screenlets, but I don wan't to use plasma, i'm using linux.

Yes, I want to do a simple widget engine, with pyqt and svg.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The desktop is controlled by the operating system/desktop shell, so methods will vary massively from one platform to another.

Comment: I forget mention that, is linux.

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2007/08/24/drawing-on-your-desktop/. PyQT or QT do not support drawing to the desktop natively, so it looks like you may have to use the pygame library. Note that this will not work for desktops that are already managed by something like plasma (or at-least, it probably won't)

Comment: In the case of Linux, the next question is which desktop environment or window manager are you using, such as Gnome or KDE? It's these that manage access to the display so any implementation will have to work with the window manager's API features. Qt only implements higher level features that are common to multiple windowing environments so that it is portable between them.

Comment: The DE actually i'm using is gnome, but soon I will change to kde, 
can I use something like python-xlib?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "images in the desktop, no images in a window". Can you elaborate? Do you just want a frameless window displaying images?

Comment: Have you tried a frameless window Qt::FramelessWindowHint with Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint?